# Domain creation: Invalid name format

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We are attempting to create a tree domain in our network. When creating the domain we are getting the error listed below.  We've double checked the naming to make sure it does not include any special characters.  If we change the ".edu" to anything else, such as ".local" it progresses without the error, but we really need to use the original domain name.  I've also listed the powershell script used to run the domain promotion below the error message:

> Install-ADDSDomain : Verification of prerequisites for Domain Controller promotion failed. The domain >DNS name "pennco.edu" has an invalid format.
>   DNS names can contain letters, numbers, and hyphens, but not spaces. Periods are used to separate domain >labels, which can be no longer than 63 bytes. The top-level domain name must contain 
>   at least one non-numeric character.
>   Characters that are not allowed include: ! " # $  & ( ) * + , ' / : ; < = > ? @ [ \ ] ^ `{ | } ~
>   Example: domain-1.microsoft.com.
>   At line:2 char:1
>   + Install-ADDSDomain`
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>      + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-ADDSDomain], TestFailedException
>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : >Test.VerifyDcPromoCore.DCPromo.General.48,Microsoft.DirectoryServices.Deployment.PowerShell.Commands.Ins>tallADDSDomainCommand

```
Import-Module ADDSDeployment
Install-ADDSDomain `
-NoGlobalCatalog:$false `
-CreateDnsDelegation:$false `
-Credential (Get-Credential) `
-DatabasePath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-DomainMode "Win2012R2" `
-DomainType "TreeDomain" `
-InstallDns:$true `
-LogPath "C:\Windows\NTDS" `
-NewDomainName "pennco.edu" `
-NewDomainNetbiosName "PENNCO" `
-ParentDomainName "PenncoDomain.edu" `
-NoRebootOnCompletion:$false `
-SiteName "Penncodomian" `
-SysvolPath "C:\Windows\SYSVOL" `
-Force:$true
```

Comment: How many existing domains/domain controllers are there?

Comment: We currently have 2 existing domain controllers on the root domain.

Comment: What if you try with "pennco.PenncoDomain.edu" ?

Comment: That would be a child domain. It will work, but we need the domain name to stay "pennco.edu" so that it will sync properly with external resources.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the other two domain controllers, we found an orphaned sub domain with the same name. Apparently my predecessor configured a second domain and removed it some point, but not completely. The error message is what threw us off.  The name was not invalid, but could not be used as an existing domain in the forest already existed.